# VHDL expression is not constant

Tags: vector, compiler-errors, vhdl

I am writing a VHDL program on quartus II for a CYCLONE III EP3C25 FPGA and I got an issue.

Here are the important part of my program:

```
odata : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);

signal buf_data : std_logic_vector(255 downto 0);

signal nb_word : integer :=0;

Process(clk,RST)
begin
    if(RST='0') then
        nb_word<=0;
    elsif(clk'event and clk='0') then
        if(Current_state_w=s2) then
            if(nb_word<=X"F0") then
                nb_word<=nb_word+16;
            else
                nb_word<=0;
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;

Process(clk,RST)

begin
    if(RST='0') then
        odata<=(OTHERS=>'0');
    elsif(clk'event and clk='0') then
            odata<=buf_data(nb_word+15 downto nb_word);
    end if;
end process;
```

This code is compiling fine but does not do what I want then I just wanted to change :

```
odata<=buf_data(nb_word+15 downto nb_word);
```

in

```
odata<=buf_data(nb_word downto nb_word-15);
```

And I changed the initialisation and reset value of nb_word at 15 instead of 0.

The problem is, when I do that and I try compiling I got this error:

```
Error (10779): VHDL error at VL_control.vhd(99): expression is not constant
```

The line corresponds to the changement of the odata line.

I really can't understand why I got this error. Why is it possible to do an addition and not a substraction? 
I also tried to define another signal and to do the substraction in the signal before addressing the buffer like that:

```
nb_word1 := (nb_word-15);
odata<=buf_data(nb_word downto nb_word1);
```

But I still get the same error. Where does that come from?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should limit `nb_word` to an integer range, that way the sythesis tool knows for sure that the value of `nb_word - 15` can not be negative.

Also, why do you compare an integer to a bit string literal? Why not just say `if nb_word < 15`?

Comment: I think you mean a natural range, but yes, that is the way to go; also comparing against an integer.

Comment: No, I mean integer range: `signal i : integer range 0 to 15;` You can use natural, which is a subtype of integer in itself.

Comment: Either works, provided he makes the other changes needed for range 0 to 15. It just seems more ... natural to me, to use the narrower type.

Comment: Actually i'm reviewing an existant code so I don't really know why he used this syntax